# Why does this specific code run faster in Python 3.11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, cpython, python-3.11

I have the following code in a Python file called `benchmark.py`:

```
source = """
for i in range(1000):
    a = len(str(i)) 
"""

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=source, number=100000))
```

When I tried to run with multiple python versions I am seeing a drastic performance difference.

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop>py -3.10 benchmark.py
16.79652149998583

C:\Users\Username\Desktop>py -3.11 benchmark.py
10.92280820000451
```

As you can see this code runs faster with python 3.11 than previous Python versions. I tried to disassemble the bytecode to understand the reason for this behaviour but I could only see a difference in opcode names (`CALL_FUNCTION` is replaced by `PRECALL` and `CALL` opcodes).

I am quite not sure if that's the reason for this performance change. so I am looking for an answer that **justifies with reference to cpython
source code**.

**`python 3.11` bytecode**:

```
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 PUSH_NULL
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000)
              8 PRECALL                  1
             12 CALL                     1
             22 GET_ITER
        >>   24 FOR_ITER                22 (to 70)
             26 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  3          28 PUSH_NULL
             30 LOAD_NAME                2 (len)
             32 PUSH_NULL
             34 LOAD_NAME                3 (str)
             36 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             38 PRECALL                  1
             42 CALL                     1
             52 PRECALL                  1
             56 CALL                     1
             66 STORE_NAME               4 (a)
             68 JUMP_BACKWARD           23 (to 24)

  2     >>   70 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             72 RETURN_VALUE
```

**`python 3.10` bytecode**:

```
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 26)
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  3          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (len)
             14 LOAD_NAME                3 (str)
             16 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 STORE_NAME               4 (a)
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4 (to 8)

  2     >>   26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

PS: I understand that *python 3.11* introduced bunch of performance improvements but I am curios to understand what optimization makes this code run faster in python 3.11

Comment: Have you tried to read [the 3.11 changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/changelog.html) to see if there's something related to the interpreter itself being optimized?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I understand that 3.11 comes with performance improvements but I am curios to understand what optimization makes this code run faster in python 3.11

Comment: Interesting question. I have no clue whatsoever, but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69821127) would... dunno... give you a starting point? Particularly what it says in the paragraph starting with _In Python 3.11, the frame object will be replaced by an array of structs that won't have an object header._ ? I insist: I have no idea. But it is an interesting question

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's scope is limited to _practical_ questions. Will knowing this detail change how you go about the practice of software development?

Comment: Are you using a class structure?  Unfortunately, using classes makes source code run slow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you know the reason for an observed speed-up, you might be better able to exploit it. If the answer is something like "it is faster because your code has feature X" and this version of Python handles this feature better than before then you might strive to write code with that feature. In any event -- who says that all questions must be practical? Striving to better understand a programming language is a valuable goal even when it has no immediate payoff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a big section in the ["what's new"](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html) page labeled ["faster runtime"](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#faster-cpython). It looks like the most likely cause of the speedup here is [PEP 659](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-659-specializing-adaptive-interpreter), which is a first start towards JIT optimization (perhaps not quite JIT *compilation*, but definitely JIT *optimization*).

Particularly, the lookup and call for `len` and `str` now bypass a lot of dynamic machinery in the overwhelmingly common case where the built-ins aren't shadowed or overridden. The global and builtin dict lookups to resolve the name get skipped in a fast path, and the underlying C routines for `len` and `str` are called directly, instead of going through the general-purpose function call handling.

You wanted source references, so here's one. The `str` call will get specialized in [`specialize_class_call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Python/specialize.c#L1356):

```
    if (tp->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_IMMUTABLETYPE) {
        if (nargs == 1 && kwnames == NULL && oparg == 1) {
            if (tp == &PyUnicode_Type) {
                _Py_SET_OPCODE(*instr, PRECALL_NO_KW_STR_1);
                return 0;
            }
```

where it detects that the call is a call to the `str` builtin with 1 positional argument and no keywords, and replaces the corresponding `PRECALL` opcode with `PRECALL_NO_KW_STR_1`. The handling for the `PRECALL_NO_KW_STR_1` opcode in the bytecode evaluation loop looks like [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Python/ceval.c#L4931):

```
        TARGET(PRECALL_NO_KW_STR_1) {
            assert(call_shape.kwnames == NULL);
            assert(cframe.use_tracing == 0);
            assert(oparg == 1);
            DEOPT_IF(is_method(stack_pointer, 1), PRECALL);
            PyObject *callable = PEEK(2);
            DEOPT_IF(callable != (PyObject *)&PyUnicode_Type, PRECALL);
            STAT_INC(PRECALL, hit);
            SKIP_CALL();
            PyObject *arg = TOP();
            PyObject *res = PyObject_Str(arg);
            Py_DECREF(arg);
            Py_DECREF(&PyUnicode_Type);
            STACK_SHRINK(2);
            SET_TOP(res);
            if (res == NULL) {
                goto error;
            }
            CHECK_EVAL_BREAKER();
            DISPATCH();
        }
```

which consists mostly of a bunch of safety prechecks and reference fiddling wrapped around a call to `PyObject_Str`, the C routine for calling `str` on an object.

Python 3.11 includes many other performance enhancements besides the above, including optimizations to stack frame creation, method lookup, common arithmetic operations, interpreter startup, and more. Most code should run much faster now, barring things like I/O-bound workloads and code that spent most of its time in C library code (like NumPy).

Comment: For fun, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQWJV.png) is what [`specialist`](https://github.com/brandtbucher/specialist) shows for this script.